# Is there a civilian aircraft that is similar to the A-10?

Tags: fairchild-a-10

This question is more out of curiosity than for any practical application, but I have wondered for a long time now if there is a civilian aircraft out there that is similar to the A-10: A relatively agile small/medium sized aircraft made primarily for VFR flight with two rear mounted turbofan engines that flies about 120 to 300 knots. I fly the A-10 in a flight simulator and sometimes wonder how close I (as a civilian) could come in real life to theoretically fly "something like that" (without breaking any laws).

There are some jets with high manoeuvrability that can be owned by civilians, like the L-39, but they are not as slow-and-stable as the A-10 (I think). And there are also a lot of medium sized business jets with two rear mounted turbo-fan engines, but they are a lot less agile and not really built for VFR.
But I have not yet seen something civilian that would fly like an A-10.

Is there any civilian aircraft that is agile enough for airshows but flies stable, is small to medium sized, built for VFR, has two rear mounted turbofan engines and flies about 120 to 300kts? (That would probably the criteria that I am looking for, I'm not interested in any weaponry)

The dream would obviously be to fly an actual A-10 (with or without weapons). But as a german civilian, that will never ever happen.

Thank you for any answers. :-)